# Can't utilize Xdebug on VScode

Tags: php, macos, docker, operating-system

Though I utilize VScode on Mac and I want to use Xdebuger for PHP on Docker, I can't use it. I've already confirmed `phpinfo()` which properly installed Xdebug and PathMappping in launch.json on VScode.

I'm sure launch.json is no matter. I guess this matter is related to Mac OS. My OS is Catalina.

I've been using Mac at work. for instance, even if I put some breakpoints using Xdebug on VScode. Xdebug can't stop proper points. Nevertheless, My co-worker can use Xdebug in the same situation. but in comparison to his pc, there is a different thing. it's Mac OS. I use Catalina which is the recent version OS but he uses Mojave which is the previous one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't specified what issue you faced specifically. Add some details about it.

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell it in detail. I've been using Mac at work. for instance, even if I put some breakpoints using Xdebug on VScode. Xdebug can't stop proper points. Nevertheless, My co-worker can use Xdebug in the same situation. but in comparison to his pc, there is a different thing. it's Mac OS. I use Catalina which is the recent version OS but he uses Mojave which is the previous one. what do you think of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add this to your question